# Hacking a BLE device

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to collect accelerometer data from a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device on to my Windows PC.

Before I start creating the code, I have been looking to connect to the device from my Windows PC to prove that is possible. The manufacturer of the BLE device only provides an iOS app so I am looking to familiarise myself with the pairing/connection procedure on Windows.

So far I have been unable to establish a connection between the BLE device and my PC. I can’t get the Bluetooth device to connect to my windows 10 PC. The BLE device is discovered but will not pair successfully.

Using `chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices` I am able to see the BLE device and that it provides three GATT services.

Until I can discover the GATT services and characteristics provided by the BLE device I am unable to start my coding. As I am new to interacting with BLE devices using code, what tools and techniques do programmers use for exploration of a BLE GATT database?

Comment: Bluetooth has evolved over *decades*. Don't expect *"it's just Bluetooth transmission"* to be a meaningful or accurate statement. That out of the way, the most straight forward way to understand how an iOS device communicates with a BLE device is to reverse-engineer the control software. *"Not a codie"* may prove to be getting in your way.

Comment: Usually any kind of system should be able to at least connect over BLE. Maybe pairing is not working since Windows sends unexpected parameters. You should use a BLE sniffer or use USBPcap to figure out what happens. Otherwise we can just speculate.

Answer (score 2):

When looking at a new BLE device, it is a good idea to use a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool to try and understand what the BLE [GATT characteristics](https://learn.adafruit.com/introduction-to-bluetooth-low-energy/gatt) look like.

On a mobile phone, the [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) is a good one to use.

On a Windows machine, if you have a recent version of the Chrome Browser, then use the URL `chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices`

It is possible that the device doesn't need to be paired, but it is difficult to know that from the informaton you have given.

Once you understand the data, then you can think about how you access the data from your other software

Comment: Thanks @ukbaz. I was able to use your recommendation on Chrome to find it. GATT connection shows not connected and I was I unable to connect it. I am able to show 3 services and a decent RSSI. I think if I can get it to connect I can dive into the services and characteristics more to find the data that I need. Any idea how to get it to connect?

Comment: What happens if you press the `inspect` button? I see this question has been closed. I think it is because you haven't given enough details. Also, this is a programming site and you haven't said what language your want to interact with the Bluetooth using. What language is the other software in that you want to connect the Bluetooth to?

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the revisions. I was so confused why it kept getting banned. Hopefully that will keep the question from being closed. 

When I hit inspect it just comes up with those three services and then characteristics under those services. The characteristics don’t seem to change so I don’t believe that is the data that the BLE device is sending. Where would you anticipate the data to be stored?

Regarding the software language, the SDK references JSON.  

Thanks for your help this far. Really appreciate it.

Comment: With BLE you need to look on the characteristic to see if it has notify as an option. If it does then you need to turn on notifications. A little tricky in the Chrome implementation. Seems like you've proved you can connect on your Windows machine. Might be better doing the rest of the investigation to the BLE data using the nRF Connect App.  Can you put a link to the SDK reference to JSON so I can see the context? otherwise that statement doesn't mean much to me.

Comment: Here’s the link to the SDK: https://csc.protee-united.com/hc/en-us/articles/216279108-ProTee-Golf-Interface-SDK

Comment: I’ve connected to the nRF app and each characteristic has notify as an option but I’m not sure if it is on or not. How can I check?

Comment: Clicking on the "three arrows pointing down" button should toggle notifications on and off. If you look at Descriptor `0x2902`, that will give you the status

Comment: Ok, got notifications to enable (although when it disconnects and then re-connects notifications are returned back to disabled). What would be the next step to see the data it is collecting?

Comment: As this is a programming site, "what's next" (now you understand the data) is always going to be about doing some programming. As you haven't expressed a preference on language, I'll assume .NET on Windows. I would split the task into 3 steps. 1) Receive the [BLE notifications](https://github.com/nexussays/ble.net). 2) Reformat the data into JSON. 3) [Send the JSON data](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/sending-and-receiving-json-using-httpclient-with-system-net-http-json) to The ProTee Golf Interface at localhost, port 9090. Do some research, have a go, and open questions if you have issues